# RTSP Programming with Java. How to read single part frames?

Tags: java, arrays, frame, rtsp

I am trying to implement RTSP Server with Java for fun.

Since I do not have any pre-knowledge about RTSP. 
I am starting with analysis already made source code.

I found those code in internet.

Link :

http://nsl.cs.sfu.ca/teaching/09/820/streaming/Client.html
http://nsl.cs.sfu.ca/teaching/09/820/streaming/Server.html
http://nsl.cs.sfu.ca/teaching/09/820/streaming/VideoStream.html
http://nsl.cs.sfu.ca/teaching/09/820/streaming/RTPpacket.html

For this posting, I got question about VideoStream.java.

it has a method like below :

```
 public int getnextframe(byte[] frame) throws Exception
  {
    int length = 0;
    String length_string;
    byte[] frame_length = new byte[5];

    //read current frame length
    fis.read(frame_length,0,5);

    //transform frame_length to integer
    length_string = new String(frame_length);
    length = Integer.parseInt(length_string);

    return(fis.read(frame,0,length));
  }
```

As you can see, it casts byte[] to String than Integer. However, in my experience, the String turns out a hexa String. So I changed like... below.

`Integer.parseInt(length_string.trim(), 16);`

It looks OK sometimes, but sometimes gets Number Format Exception.
When I print `length_string` variables, it show in console like `iso2a, vc1mp, 41��� ...`.

I can not know what I am missing here. Can you explain what is the purpose of codes here?

```
length_string = new String(frame_length);
length = Integer.parseInt(length_string);
```

P.S

Is there anyone knows full implementation of these code or other samples which does not uses extra third party libs, it could be much help for me.

Comment: I would guess that, if they're *not* hex, then your modification makes it read the wrong length. Then (since it read the wrong number of bytes from the previous frame) it thinks the next frame starts at the wrong place. Maybe. Just a guess.

Comment: @immibis I found the problem. This code only support Mjpeg format. However I put mp4 format. So VideoStream can not read stream :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to myself to close this question.

Each video types has its own data structure.

In this case, I set data type for 'MJPEG', but I load 'MPEG' file.

So bytes array appears weird way.

- FYI, MJPEG is just pack of jpeg. So every frame is key frame.
- Other type I handled before, for instance, TS file, has i-frames and b-frames. Former one has clear image since it is key frame. However second one looks broken since it is not a key frame.